# Superman/Supergirl in ancient Rome/Germany?

Tags: dc, superman, episode-identification, supergirl

I recently found this image online, and I would LOVE to know what comic it is from.  I am a huge ancient Rome fan, and this looks like a very intriguing scene.  Especially because, at least the way I'm seeing it, Supergirl seems to be in opposition to Superman, facing off with him in solidarity with the German warriors behind her.

Can anyone identify the story that had Superman and Supergirl living in the Roman Empire?

[image: Roman Superman and German Supergirl]

Comment: This isn't from a comic, it's an unofficial image. http://stevenhoward.deviantart.com/art/Celtic-Supergirl-CSBG-280319630

Comment: That's too bad...I would have read that comic.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question, as the question was based on a false pretense.

Comment: Such a shame this doesn't exist. I would totally read this comic :/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

##### Per Gorchestopher's comment, the above image is a deviantart (i.e. fanmade) picture by [Stephen Howard](http://stevenhoward.deviantart.com/art/Celtic-Supergirl-CSBG-280319630) showing a "Celtic Supergirl", part of a series of 73 "[out of time](https://goodcomics.comicbookresources.com/2012/01/18/the-line-it-is-drawn-73-comic-book-characters-in-different-eras/)" images suggested by fans.

On the subject of Superheroes in Ancient Rome, there *have* been some time-travel stories you may be interested in including "Lois Lane, Slave Girl!" (from [Superman's Girlfriend Vol 1, #33](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Superman%27s_Girl_Friend,_Lois_Lane_Vol_1_33)). Lois is transported in time and sold as a slave.

[image: Lois Lane, Slave Girl]

["Challenge of the Superfriends - The Time Trap"](https://www.jabootu.com/cotsftt.htm) in which Superman, Batman and Robin are transported to Ancient Rome to face fearsome lions (well, one arthritic-looking lion at any rate) in Caesar's gladiatorial arena.

[image: Challenge of the Superfriends]

And "[World's Finest #198](https://dc.wikia.com/wiki/World%27s_Finest_Vol_1_198)" in which a pyjama-clad Jimmy Olsen is sent back in time by Superman and the Flash's speed challenge. He faces a Centurion who (unsurprisingly) decides to kill him.

[image: Jimmy Olsen]